# error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'train'

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing a face recognition project. But i keep getting an errorr which told me: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'train'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - Can't parse 'src'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
> - Can't parse 'src'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

I had review my code several times and i still cannot find the error in my code. Hope anyone helps.

```
#import OpenCV module
import cv2
#import os module for reading training data directories and paths
import os
import sys
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

def face_detect(img):
    #image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    #convert the test image to gray image as opencv face detector expects gray images
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # HaarCascade file, to detect the face.
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/content/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    grays = []
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)

    #if no faces are detected then return original img
    if(len(faces) == 0):
        return None, None
    
    # For drawing rectangles over multiple faces in the image
    #for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        #cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    # Show Detected faces.
    #cv2_imshow(image)
    #cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    # Append the detected faces into grays list.
    for i in range(0, len(faces)):
        (x, y, w, h) = faces[i]
        grays.append(gray[y:y+w, x:x+h])
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Detecting Face -\-")
    return grays, faces

def training_data(data_folder_path):
    dirs = os.listdir(data_folder_path)
    #list to hold all subject faces
    faces = []
    #list to hold labels for all subjects
    labels = []
    for dir_name in dirs:
        if not dir_name.startswith("s"):
            continue;
        label = int(dir_name.replace("s", ""))
        subject_dir_path = data_folder_path + "/" + dir_name
        subject_images_names = os.listdir(subject_dir_path)
        for image_name in subject_images_names:
            if image_name.startswith("."):
                continue;
            image_path = subject_dir_path + "/" + image_name
            #read image
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            # Show Detected faces.
            cv2_imshow(image)
            cv2.waitKey(100)
            face, rect = face_detect(image)
            if face is not None:
                faces.append(face)
                labels.append(label)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()    
    return faces, labels

#let's first prepare our training data
#data will be in two lists of same size
#one list will contain all the faces
#and other list will contain respective labels for each face
faces, labels = training_data("/content/training-data")
#print total faces and labels
print("Total faces: ", len(faces))
print("Total labels: ", len(labels))
#create our LBPH face recognizer 
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
#train our face recognizer of our training faces
face_recognizer.train(faces, np.array(labels))

def draw_rectangle(img, rect):
    (x, y, w, h) = rect
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

label = ["", "Pei Han", "Tan"]
def predict(test_img):
    img = test_img.copy()
    print("\n")
    print("Face Prediction Running -\-")
    face, rect = face_detect(img)
    print(len(face), "faces detected.")
    for i in range(0, len(face)):
        labeltemp = face_recognizer.predict(face[i])
        label_text = label[labeltemp]
        draw_rectangle(img, rect)
        cv2.putText(img, str(label_text), (i), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    return img

# Read the test image.
test_img = "/content/test-data/test.jpg"
predicted_img = predict(test_img)
#cv2.imshow(label[1], predicted_img)
cv2_imshow(predicted_img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Recognized faces = "), label
```

Comment: There's no `train` function in your script... Do you mean `face_recognizer.train`?

Comment: Yes, i man face_recognizer.train